# Bootstrap4: Extra whitespace on right side of the screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, width, navbar

My navbar at the top of the page is overflowing the viewport on smaller devices. I found this on my personal device and in the Chrome developer tools.

Starting at 575px there is a whitespace on the white side of the screen. As the viewport decreases, the whitespace inversely increases. At the smallest point the content takes up about 25% and the remaining 75% is white.

How can I make this extra whitespace go away? Thanks!

```js
< script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
integrity = "sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
crossorigin = "anonymous" > < /script>

  <
  script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
integrity = "sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
crossorigin = "anonymous" > < /script>

  <
  script src = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
integrity = "sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
crossorigin = "anonymous" > < /script>
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  position: inherit;
}

#home {
  background-image: url(jumbotronNewResized.jpg);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 55px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#lowerJumbotron {
  color: white;
}

i {
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="fontawesome-free-5.11.2-web/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>My App!</title>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#topPageNavbar" data-offset="100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-secondary fixed-top" id="topPageNavbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold" href="#">My App Page</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topNavbar" aria-controls="topNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#download">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-xs-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" aria-label="Email Address">

        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password">

        <button class="btn btn-outline-success bg-success my-2 my-sm-0 text-white font-weight-bold" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="home">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-4">My Awesome App!</h1>
      <p class="lead">This is why YOU should download this fantastic app!</p>
      <hr class="my-2">
      <p id="lowerJumbotron">Want to keep updated? Join our mailing list!</p>
      <form>
        <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
              </div>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="about" class="container">
    <h3 class="my-3">This is all about the app!</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <hr class="container">
  <div id="features" class="container mt-4">
    <h3 class="mb-3">Check out some of the different features!</h3>
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="seedsResized.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Seeds">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-seedling icon"></i>Gather Your Seed</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="sprout.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Sprouting Seeds">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-leaf icon"></i>Nuture Your Field</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="harvestResized.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-tractor icon"></i>Receive Your Harvest</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-deck mt-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="calendar.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>Plan Your Activity</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="meetingResized.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i>Schedule Your Success</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="dashboardResized.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>Monitor Your Growth</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="download"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Link of the Website With Extra Whitespace On Small Screens](https://www.williamswebworks.net/project)

Comment: Please put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the navigation, the issue is with the horizontal ruler `<hr>` having a 100% width; add the following CSS to resolve:

```
hr.container {
    width: auto;
}
```

complete **working snippet**:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  position: inherit;
}

#home {
  background-image: url(jumbotronNewResized.jpg);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 55px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#lowerJumbotron {
  color: white;
}

i {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

hr.container {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="fontawesome-free-5.11.2-web/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#topPageNavbar" data-offset="100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-secondary fixed-top" id="topPageNavbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold" href="#">My App Page</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topNavbar" aria-controls="topNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#download">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-xs-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" aria-label="Email Address">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success bg-success my-2 my-sm-0 text-white font-weight-bold" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="home">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-4">My Awesome App!</h1>
      <p class="lead">This is why YOU should download this fantastic app!</p>
      <hr class="my-2">
      <p id="lowerJumbotron">Want to keep updated? Join our mailing list!</p>
      <form>
        <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
              </div>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="about" class="container">
    <h3 class="my-3">This is all about the app!</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <br>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  </div>
  <hr class="container">
  <div id="features" class="container mt-4">
    <h3 class="mb-3">Check out some of the different features!</h3>
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="seedsResized.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Seeds">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-seedling icon"></i>Gather Your Seed</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="sprout.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Sprouting Seeds">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-leaf icon"></i>Nuture Your Field</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="harvestResized.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-tractor icon"></i>Receive Your Harvest</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-deck mt-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="calendar.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>Plan Your Activity</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="meetingResized.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i>Schedule Your Success</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="dashboardResized.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>Monitor Your Growth</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-wrap">Click This Link!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="download"></div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for your help!